# PHP extract value from a string that is between <star>t and <end>

Tags: php, string, extract

I want to extract some values from a string (result of a db query).
An example of such a string is:

```
$data="tostore1:1 = INTEGER: 10000000
       tostore1:2 = INTEGER: 1000000
       something else something else
       tostore2:1 = STRING: 'test1'
       something else something else
       tostore2:2 = STRING: 'test2'
       tostore3:1 = INTEGER: 1000";
```

I would get two arrays. One containing `10000000`, `'test1'` and `1000` and one containing `1000000`, `'test2'`.

In alternative, if I want to extract `tostore2:1` value, the start could be `tostore2:1` and the end `CR LF` @ the end of the line

I'm searching for the most optimized way for do that

Comment: I don't see "<star>t" nor "<end>" as stated in your title?

Answer (score 1):

Using simple regular expression

```
$result = array();
$pattern = "/tostore\d+:(\d+)\s+=\s+[A-Z]+:\s+('?)([\d\w]+)(\2?)/i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $m);

$keys = $m[1];
$values = $m[3];
$len = count($keys);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $result[$keys[$i]][]=$values[$i];
}

$arr1 = $result[1];
$arr2 = $result[2];
```